# jQuery click event problem in firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following click event which calls a codeigniter method to update my database.  It is used to track clicks on links.  It is working in IE9, but not in Firefox 3.6.3.

```
$(".link").click(function(event) {
    $.get('<?= base_url() ?>ajax/click_out/' + $(this).attr("site_id"));
});
```

It is calling the right php file and sending the right information, but getting an empty response.  If I add an alert after the get, it works, and it also works if I prevent the default event.  Is it possible that firefox isn't completing the ajax because the code is gone as soon as a new page is loaded?

To test this, I modified the code to:

```
$(".link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    $.get('<?= base_url() ?>ajax/click_out/' + $(this).attr("site_id"));
    window.document.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

I thought that it would have to wait to redirect until the get is completed, but that doesn't work either.  If I take out the redirect but leave the preventDefault in, it tracks the click just fine (but obviously doesn't send the user to the site.

In case it is needed, the html of the link is:

```
<a href="<?= $url ?>" site_id="<?= $site_id ?>" class="link"><?= $title ?></a>
```

I am very new to jQuery and javascript and would appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 3):

you can redirect the user to the site when the `get` request completes by redirecting the user in the `success` callback like

```
$(".link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    $.get('<?= base_url() ?>ajax/click_out/' + $(this).attr("site_id"),function(){
        window.document.location.href = link.href;

});

});
```

have a look here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but you could try something like this...

```
$.get("test.php", function(data){
    window.document.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```